# In Splunk , how to set fixed colour for bars in column chart?

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

In Splunk, how do I set a fixed colour for bars in column chart?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking at a SimpleXML dashboard, you need to add something like the following. There should be an Edit XML button on your dashboard/chart.

The following example makes the ERROR column always red, the WARN column always yellow and so-on and so-forth.

```
<option name="charting.fieldColors">
  {"ERROR": 0xFF0000, "WARN": 0xFF9900, "INFO":0x009900, "NULL":0xC4C4C0}
</option>
```

Refer to https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.5/Viz/BuildandeditdashboardswithSimplifiedXML#Specify_custom_colors_for_fields_in_charts

Comment: This is correct. The Splunk forums have examples with square brackets, which does not work. Changing to "{}" brackets got it working for me.